# $n!+1$ is composite for infinitely many odd $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It's the number theory problem from Thailand Mathematical Olympiad. That require one to prove that $n!+1$ is composite for infinitely many odd $n$.

It's true if $n$ is even from Wilson's theorem directly that $p \text { } \Big|\Big((p-1)!+1\Big)$ but for odd $n$ I have no idea about it. I've tried for prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$ and we'll have that $\left(\dfrac{p-1}{2}\right)!\equiv\pm 1\pmod p$ and maybe there is infinitely many cases that $\left(\dfrac{p-1}{2}\right)!\equiv -1\pmod p$, but I don't know how to prove it and I don't think this is a good way to tackle this problem.

I, actually, saw someone's proof before but I didn't pay attention at much and didn't jot down the idea. All in my memory is that he used Bertrand postulate and something in the double factorial like $(n!+1)!+1$. Any help would be really appreciate and thank you in advance.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Not sure I see the duplicate here.  The present question specifies that $n$ is odd while the link shows the (obvious) fact that $(p-1)! +1$ is composite for odd primes $p$...but of course $p-1$ is even.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @lulu. Yes, you are right. I have confused it with the prime divisors of $n!+1$. So $n!+1$ is divisible by $p$ and $q$ with $p\neq q$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  No worries, just thought I might be missing something simple.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1843621p12399279